# Rails HABTM - Properly removing an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am developing a feature for creating specials, for a shopping website. One product can have more than one special, and obviously a special can have more than one product..

I am using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, so i have declared:

Product.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :specials
```

Special.rb

```
has_and belongs_to_many :products
```

Now, with a product `@product` and a special `@special`, an association is created like so..

```
@special.products << @product
```

After doing this, the following is true:

```
@special.products.first == @product
```

**and, importantly:**

```
@product.specials.first == @special
```

When i delete the association using this

```
@special.products.delete(@product)
```

then `@product` is removed from specials, so `@special.products.first==nil`, however `@product` **still contains** `@special`, in other words `@products.specials.first==@special`

Is there any proper way, apart from writing a delete method, to do this in a single call?

Comment: And by the way, why are the backticks not turning the words into code? Sorry, this is my first post on Stackoverflow

Comment: `backticks` only work for strings - if you have blocks of code, you should indent by 4 spaces

Comment: I think it does remove the association both ways, have you tried reloading `@special` ?

Comment: xlembouras is correct. `@special.products.delete(@product)` actually does remove the association on both sides, as it deletes the record in the join table (ie `product_specials`). Try `@product.reload.specials` or telling `.specials` to re-fetch the join table records by passing it `true`, like so `@product.specials(true)`. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-reload).

Comment: You also can use three backticks at before the first line, and three at the last time. If you wanna force color coding you can write it after the first three backticks like so `'''ruby \n def myCode end \n '''`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

[According to the Rails documentation:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)

> **collection.delete(object, …)**
>
> Removes one or more objects from the
>   collection by removing their associations from the join table. This
>   does not destroy the objects.

[Brilliant reference here for you](http://neyric.com/2007/07/08/how-to-delete-a-many-to-many-association-with-rails/)

You can use:

```
product = Product.find(x)
special = product.specials.find(y)

product.specials.delete(special)
```

This creates ActiveRecord objects for both the object you're trying to remove, which gives clear definition to the function

> **collection.clear**
>
> Removes all objects from the
>   collection by removing their associations from the join table. This
>   does not destroy the objects.

In this example:

```
product = Product.find(x)

product.specials.clear
```

Comment: Should mention that calling `delete` on a `has_and_belongs_to_many` will automatically commit the removal to the database by deleting the row from the join table.